# Determine if a DataSet column contains entirely identical data

Tags: c#

I have a DataSet similar to the one below:

```
ID    Name    Data1   Data2
1     MM      X       1000
2     ST      Y       1000
3     EC      Z       1000
4     JT      T       1000
```

I display this `DataSet` in a `DataGridView` by binding the `DataSet`.  What I would like to do is set the visibility of the `Data2` column based on if all the data is similar or not.

So in the above example, I would want to hide the `Data2` column because the data represented is common to all elements in the `DataSet`.  But if any of the elements had a unique entry for that column, I would want the column to be visible.

Is there a way to do this without iterating over the `DataSet`?  I prefer not to iterate as my `DataSet`s are quite large and I want to perform this check for multiple columns.

Comment: No, you would have to iterate the Dataset one way or the other.

Comment: dataGrid.Columns["Data2"].Visible = (dataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView.ToTable(true, "Data2").Rows.Count != 1);

This is the approach I settled on.  The ToTable() function of a DataSet contains a flag where you are ask it only to grab the distinct values.  So I simply check if more than one distinct value was pulled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some LINQ to check to see how many distinct values you have in that column:

```
if(dataTable.AsEnumerable().Select(row => row["Data2"]).Distinct().Count() > 1)
{
    // Make column invisible
}
```

If there is more than 1 distinct value, then you know that not all of the values are equal.

Answer (score 0):

```
var areSame = dt.Rows.Count > 0 && 
              dt.AsEnumerable().All(x => dt.rows[0]["Data2"].Equlas(x["Data2"]));
```